# Add bean functionality from consuming project

Tags: java, spring, zk, spring-bean

I have two projects, A and B. B consumes A as a jar. B is not always used in other projects (for example, projects C, D, E, etc. can either consume or not consume B, but always consume A). I can modify both projects.

There is a controller in A that I want to add functionalities related to B's bussiness model (entities, services, that kind of stuff). Of course, writing the new functionality in A won't work (compiling mainly, but also would break the well-defined structure of both projects).

The controller in A is defined as a spring bean in the Java class itself, and also is related to a zul page that uses it. Relevant code:

Java

```
@Controller("userController")
@Scope("prototype")
public class UserController extends GenericForwardComposer
```

ZUL page

```
<window apply="${userController}" >
```

How could I add the functionality in B and avoid as much possible unnecesary complexity? I want to avoid extending the controller and adding a @Primary definition. Since I'm working with Java 8, I was thinking on interfaces with default behaviour, but I haven't figured how to make the execution pick an interface in B rather than in A. Composition is also an option, but the bean in A wouldn't be properly initializated (there are components in the zul page).

Any help or pointers will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

From a ZK's perspective there's nothing to do here. So no need to look in this direction. (based on the details/code provided so far - unless your last comment ...

> there are components in the zul page

... means/should indicate something specific)

It rather seems to be a Spring topic, how to resolve duplicate bean definitions (default in A, something advanced in B), if you don't like `@Primary` then maybe `@Priority`/`@Order` can help to determine which bean get's injected.

Another way to manage such scenarios are spring profiles or more general the @Conditional annotations which allow dynamic configuration/instantiation of beans.
E.g. [spring-boot auto-configuration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.x/reference/html/boot-features-developing-auto-configuration.html) as these `@ConditionalOn...`-annotations, which I [used in zk-springboot-autoconfig](https://github.com/zkoss/zkspringboot/blob/master/zkspringboot-autoconfig/src/main/java/org/zkoss/zkspringboot/ZkAutoConfiguration.java#L58) de-/activate beans based on the existence of certain classes on the classpath, or other conditions based on properties.

There are many ways to achieve a dynamic bean configuration in spring. In case you need dedicated help with ZK you can try the [zk forum](https://forum.zkoss.org/) or [zk support](https://www.zkoss.org/support/) (disclaimer: I work for ZK)

Comment: I'm not working with spring boot, so some annotations are not available for me. At the end, I ended using the "extends" approach, it's a bit complex but it works. Thanks for the input though.

Comment: yes that's why I provided a few alternatives... glad you found something that works in your case